# Adding a N/A Value to a Converted Datetime Field

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a query which contains two columns which are Datetime fields; they are REVIEW_START_DT and REVIEW_END_DT.  I convert both the column date format into Day-Month-Year format. If a Cell has a Null value in either column,  the Null value to be replaced with an 'N/A' value. I have tried to write this into the program, but I still am getting Null values. I can't figure out why.

```
SELECT 
ASSESSMENT_ID,
Reviewer_Name,
Examinee_Name,
Assessment_Type,
Assessment_Status,
CASE when REPLACE(CONVERT (varchar(9), REVIEW_START_DT, 6), ' ', '-') =NUll then 'N/A'
else REPLACE(CONVERT (varchar(9), REVIEW_START_DT, 6), ' ', '-') end as REVIEW_START_DT, 
CASE when 
 REPLACE(CONVERT (varchar(9), REVIEW_END_DT, 6), ' ', '-')=NUll then 'N/A'
else  REPLACE(CONVERT (varchar(9), REVIEW_END_DT, 6), ' ', '-') end  as REVIEW_END_DT, 
Assessment_Link
  FROM [New_EEs].[dbo].[vw_SBC_Assessment_Assignments]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One tests `null` with *`IS`* not `=` as in: `if x is null ...` because *nothing* is equal to `NULL`.

```
REPLACE(CONVERT (varchar(9), REVIEW_END_DT, 6), ' ', '-') IS NULL THEN 'N/A'
```

or

```
ISNULL(REPLACE(CONVERT (varchar(9), REVIEW_END_DT, 6), ' ', '-'), 'N/A')
```

Better

```
CASE WHEN REVIEW_START_DT IS NULL THEN 'N/A' 
  ELSE REPLACE(CONVERT (varchar(9), REVIEW_START_DT, 6), ' ', '-') 
END
```

Comment: `Coalesce()` > `IsNull()` http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/coalesce-vs-isnull-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Coalesce()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function:

```
SELECT Coalesce(Cast(Replace(REVIEW_START_DR, ' ', '-') As char(10)), 'N/A')
```